# IE SCRIPT5 Access is denied http:/ip/file.swf iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe

I have a page with iframe that have src set to some flash on a different ip. If I click on any link inside my page (not in iframe) or close the browser i get:

Script error 
"An error has occurred in the script on this page"

Line: 1 
Char: 1
Error: Access is denied 
Code:0 
url: http://ip/file.swf

"Do you want to contunu running scripts on this page?"

This only happens in IE.

Anyone know how to solve this?